# Which one Expensive @DbRef or Manual Reference

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I haven't enough knowledge of mongodb. But after searching about `DbRef` and manual references I came up with result that we should avoid `DbRef`. `DbRef` makes an additional request to load data, but the same condition applies in manual reference - we will hit extra query to load entity. So is there any use case which clearly argues for using `DbRef` over manual ref?

I am going to work on very large application, so it will help me a lot because these things are heart of projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main (and not that impressive) advantage of `DbRef` is driver support, so it might save you few lines of code for dereferencing. 
Also, `DbRef` format allows you to specify the collection and database you target. In some very complex scenarios that might be helpful. In most use cases however this is not required, as you usually reference records in specific a collection in the same database (e.g. a book item will reference item in authors, so there's no need to specify the collection and database for each record).